# Conversion from char to int

Tags: c++, char, type-conversion

I'm studying the C++ language by three weeks and I have a problem with the conversion from char to int.If I write this program :

```
int main()
{
  int a = 200; 
  char h = a; 
  int b = h;
  cout << h << "\n"; 
  cout << b << "\n"; 

  keep_window_open();
  return 0;
}
```

If i convert the value of a to char the value of h becomes a character present on the ASCII table, but if i convert the h value back to int I don't get back the value 200, why ?.

Comment: Your system's `char` must default to signed.

Comment: Which compiler and architecture are you using here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On systems that have 8 bit chars (ie, most of them), 200 is out of range because char is signed and you only have 7 bits to store the value in.

Comment: I believe it is implementation defined whether `char` defaults to signed or unsigned.

Comment: @TimoGeusch so why if i print out the value of the char variable that's the right value ?

Comment: `char` may be the equivalent of either `signed char` or `unsigned char`.  Historically, most (but not all) machines with 8 bit `char` and 2's complement make it signed; most others make it unsigned (which is a lot more logical for text).  Today, most compilers have an option so you can choose: `/J` for MSC, `-funsigned-char` for g++, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

`char` can be signed or unsigned, the implementation must document which (yours is signed).
The size is also implementation-defined (ID) (Yours is 8 bit, really common).

Also, conversions are defined to be value-preserving where possible.

So:

```
200 (int)
-56 (char) ID as not in range for char and char is signed
-56 (int) value-preserving widening conversion
```

Is your conversion sequence.

> #### 6.3.1.3 Signed and unsigned integers
>
> 1 When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type other than `_Bool`, if
>   the value can be represented by the new type, it is unchanged.
>   2 Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or
>   subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type
>   until the value is in the range of the new type.60)
>   3 Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the
>   result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.

Answer (score 0):

Because the value `200` doesn't fit in a `char`, at least on
most machines.  If the range of a `char` is `[-128,127]`
(usually the case), when you convert `200` to a `char`, you get
an implementation defined value (which could even be a signal,
but most likely -56).

Of course, -56 isn't a legal value in any encoding I know of,
but most of the output devices will treat it as if it were an
`unsigned char`, with the value of 200.  There are places where
you have to pay attention, however; the functions in `<cctype>`,
for example, expecct their arguments to be in the range
`[0, UCHAR_MAX]`, and will result in undefined behavior if you
pass them -56.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the same value you have to use `unsigned char`. For example

```
unsigned char h = a;
```

According to the C++ Standard (4.7 Integral conversions)

> 3 If the destination type is signed, the value is unchanged if it can
>   be represented in the destination type (and bit-field width);
>   otherwise, the value is implementation-defined.

It seems that by default your compiler considers type `char` as behaving as type `signed char` Value 200 can not be represented in signed char beacuse the maximum value for type signed char is `127` so the bit combination that corresponds to 200 is interpretated as signed number `-56`. When it is assigned back to an object of type int then this value that is -56 is assigned to.